# text formatting error

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a model ..

```
class News(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    text = models.TextField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return ('view_item', None, {'slug': self.slug})

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "News"
```

and the template file is as follows

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block title %}Welcome to my blog{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

    {% if news %}
        {% for singleitem in news %}
            <h2>{{ singleitem.title }}</h2>
            <p>{{ singleitem.date }}</p>
            {{ singleitem.text }}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}

{% endblock %}
```

the input in the textbox is as follows

```
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam pharetra aliquet arcu. Praesent non elit dolor, vel bibendum lectus. Proin mauris nisl, faucibus sit amet commodo et, interdum a ligula. Ut sapien leo, egestas non molestie vitae, aliquam eget purus. Sed at libero sapien. Ut id dolor elit. Ut placerat massa massa. Quisque posuere pellentesque lorem ac tristique. Nam lacinia tincidunt felis ac adipiscing. Suspendisse elit risus, cursus vel dignissim et, lacinia sit amet neque. Morbi tincidunt sem id augue fermentum adipiscing.
</p>

<p>
Quisque commodo lorem eu tortor auctor sodales. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent condimentum ante id erat dapibus ac rhoncus dui hendrerit. Curabitur at diam vitae ipsum sagittis vestibulum ac et metus. Donec in molestie justo. In eget fringilla lacus. Vestibulum gravida quam quis dui aliquam ut gravida justo rhoncus. Nam euismod mattis purus pulvinar scelerisque. Nam tortor augue, cursus vel ultrices ut, pharetra id leo. Etiam tristique, augue aliquam faucibus dictum, libero justo egestas ante, ut volutpat metus nunc vitae arcu. Aliquam erat volutpat. Sed laoreet posuere sodales.
</p>

<p>
Donec urna urna, facilisis cursus auctor quis, eleifend nec diam. Proin eros dolor, aliquet ut euismod a, viverra sit amet turpis. Suspendisse at dolor quam. Phasellus suscipit rhoncus nisl at feugiat. Aenean in adipiscing purus. Etiam non ligula ligula. Nulla sit amet urna libero, et suscipit nulla. Suspendisse congue purus a eros accumsan eu volutpat ante euismod. Proin ut massa turpis, in gravida diam. Maecenas metus dui, cursus sed commodo eget, accumsan nec arcu.
</p>
```

which is displayed as follows, django doesn't recognize html tags

> <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
>   Etiam pharetra aliquet arcu. Praesent non elit dolor, vel bibendum
>   lectus. Proin mauris nisl, faucibus sit amet commodo et, interdum a
>   ligula. Ut sapien leo, egestas non molestie vitae, aliquam eget purus.
>   Sed at libero sapien. Ut id dolor elit. Ut placerat massa massa.
>   Quisque posuere pellentesque lorem ac tristique. Nam lacinia tincidunt
>   felis ac adipiscing. Suspendisse elit risus, cursus vel dignissim et,
>   lacinia sit amet neque. Morbi tincidunt sem id augue fermentum
>   adipiscing. </p>
>
> <p> Quisque commodo lorem eu tortor auctor sodales. Lorem ipsum
>   dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent condimentum ante
>   id erat dapibus ac rhoncus dui hendrerit. Curabitur at diam vitae
>   ipsum sagittis vestibulum ac et metus. Donec in molestie justo. In
>   eget fringilla lacus. Vestibulum gravida quam quis dui aliquam ut
>   gravida justo rhoncus. Nam euismod mattis purus pulvinar scelerisque.
>   Nam tortor augue, cursus vel ultrices ut, pharetra id leo. Etiam
>   tristique, augue aliquam faucibus dictum, libero justo egestas ante,
>   ut volutpat metus nunc vitae arcu. Aliquam erat volutpat. Sed laoreet
>   posuere sodales. </p>
>
> <p> Donec urna urna, facilisis cursus auctor quis, eleifend nec
>   diam. Proin eros dolor, aliquet ut euismod a, viverra sit amet turpis.
>   Suspendisse at dolor quam. Phasellus suscipit rhoncus nisl at feugiat.
>   Aenean in adipiscing purus. Etiam non ligula ligula. Nulla sit amet
>   urna libero, et suscipit nulla. Suspendisse congue purus a eros
>   accumsan eu volutpat ante euismod. Proin ut massa turpis, in gravida
>   diam. Maecenas metus dui, cursus sed commodo eget, accumsan nec arcu.
>   </p>

how to format text for output using django output field?

//yousuf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the "safe" filter. Like `{{ singleitem.text|safe }}`. I think thats what you are looking for.